# How to change the color of text to the mix of other colors (other part of image)?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color-theory

I'm trying to make a text like this one here in Photoshop and i have no idea how to do that.

If this a big question, just give me a subject to search about it.

[image: Question Goal Sample Image]

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Sina Mohammadi, thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. We are not a tutorial-on-demand site. If you have any questions, please see the help center or ping one of us in the Graphic Design Chat once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paint the text in white, no need to rasterize it.

Change its mode to Difference.

Now it will show the opposite colors.

Image below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Greyscale image.

- Chose `Layer > New Adjustment Layer > Invert` and click `OK` (ignore what it does to the image right now)
- Set your type on a layer above the adjustment layer.
- Command/Ctrl+click the Type Layer thumbnail in the **Layers Panel** to load the type as a selection.
- Turn off visibility for the type layer.
- Highlight the Adjustment Layer Mask and fill the selection with black.
- Deselect All (Command/Ctrl+d)
- Choose `Image > Adjustments > invert` to invert the mask

Done.

[image]

- From here you refine as desired by adjusting the mask.